# Website Pulls Correct Fonts Only When Clicking Certain Links, Will Otherwise Pull From System Fonts

Tags: html, css, font-face

I'm having the problem described in the post title with my portfolio website, and I'm really at a loss as to what the problem could be. The "Work" and "Contact" pages won't pull the correct fonts even if I navigate to them using my dropdown links, and individual project pages only pull the proper fonts if I navigate to one of the projects from the home page (after clicking the logo on the top left to get the fonts to load at all), and then use previous and next buttons at the end of each project. I've checked all references to files within folders, and everything seems to be in order. The site's URL is mtbailey.com, and I've attached a screenshot of what things should look like if everything works the way it's supposed. Does anyone have any idea what's going on?

https://gyazo.com/d478ce4471e5944eae44af5fcef3c281

CSS:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Spartan MB';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url("../fonts/SpartanMB/SpartanMB-Regular.eot"); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url("../fonts/SpartanMB/SpartanMB-Regular.eot?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
         url("../fonts/SpartanMB/SpartanMB-Regular.woff") format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
         url("../fonts/SpartanMB/SpartanMB-Regular.woff2") format('woff2'), /* Modern Browsers */
         url("../fonts/SpartanMB/SpartanMB-Regular.ttf") format('truetype'); /* Safari, Android, iOS */
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Spartan MB';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
    src: url('../fonts/SpartanMB/SpartanMB-SemiBold.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('../fonts/SpartanMB/SpartanMB-SemiBold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
         url('../fonts/SpartanMB/SpartanMB-SemiBold.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
         url('../fonts/SpartanMB/SpartanMB-SemiBold.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Modern Browsers */
         url('../fonts/SpartanMB/SpartanMB-SemiBold.ttf') format('truetype'); /* Safari, Android, iOS */
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Spartan MB';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 900;
    src: url('../fonts/SpartanMB/SpartanMB-ExtraBold.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('../fonts/SpartanMB/SpartanMB-ExtraBold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
         url('../fonts/SpartanMB/SpartanMB-ExtraBold.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
         url('../fonts/SpartanMB/SpartanMB-ExtraBold.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Modern Browsers */
         url('../fonts/SpartanMB/SpartanMB-ExtraBold.ttf') format('truetype'); /* Safari, Android, iOS */
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

strong {
    font-weight: 600;
}

html, body {
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    font-kerning: normal;
    -webkit-font-kerning: normal;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Spartan MB';
}


li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}

p {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1em;
}

hr {
    background-color: #293941;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1.2px;
    float: left
    width: 100%;
}

h1 {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 8vw;
    -webkit-margin-after: 0;
    -webkit-margin-before: 0;
}

h2 {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 4vw;
    -webkit-margin-after: 0;
    -webkit-margin-before: 0;
}

h3 {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 0;
    -webkit-margin-before: 0;
}

input[type=text] {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #293941;
    padding: 3px 0px;
    font-family: Spartan MB;
    font-size: 1em;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
}

input[type=submit] {
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: Spartan MB;
    background-color: #25bcbd;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.35em;
    cursor: pointer;
}

textarea {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #293941;
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 600px;
    height: 200px;
    font-family: Spartan MB;
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 3px 0px;
    margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
}

.teal {
    color: #25bcbd;
}

.blue {
    color: #2F90BB;
}

.mobileimg {
    display: block;
}

.desktopimg {
    display: none;
}

.footnote{
    font-size: 0.6em;
    margin: 0.6em 0 0 1 em;
}

#wrap {
    margin-top: 80px; /*Same as Header height*/
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 600px;
    position: relative;
    color: #293941;
    padding: 0 1vw;
}


#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 82px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 2;
}

#headerwrap {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 600px;
    position: relative;
    color: #293941;
    padding: 0 1vw;
    height: 82px;
    background-color: white;
}

.mobileheaderbar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #293941;
    float: left;
}

#header img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

#logo {
    width: 160px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    display: none;
}

#dhr {
    height: 3px;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 2px solid #293941;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #293941;
    float: left;
}

#squarelogo {
    width: 45px;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

#nav {
    display: none;
    float: right;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 23px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    width: 20%;
}

#nav a {
    color: #293941;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}

input, button, submit {
    border: none;
    padding: 0px;
}

.dropbtn {
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 60px;
    height: 80px;
    background-image: url("../images/hamburger.svg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: white;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    min-width: 160px;
    overflow: auto;
    right: 0px;
    font-family: 'Spartan MB';
    font-weight: 900;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    color: #293941;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #293941;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #e5e5e5}

.show {display:block;}

#landing {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #293941;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

#lndmain {
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
}

#lndside {
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    line-height: 2;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
}

#lndmain h1{
    font-size: 3em;
    padding-top: 25px;
}

#lndmain h2{
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
}

#lndside h1 {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1em;
}

.projlogo {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}

.projdesc {
    float: left;
    padding-bottom: 3.4%;
}

.projdesc p {
    margin: 0;
}

.projdesc h1 {
    line-height: 1.2;
    margin-top: 3%;
}

.twocolumn {
    -webkit-columns: 1 0px;
    -moz-columns: 1 0px;
    columns: 1 0px;

    float: left;
}

.thumb {
    float: left;
    margin: 3.4% 0px;

    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    break-inside: avoid;
}

.thumb h1 {
    line-height: 1;
    margin-top: 3%;
}

.more {
    font-size: 5vw;
    font-weight: 900;
}

.prevnext {
    font-size: 5vw;
    font-weight: 900;
    display: inline;
}

.fade:hover  {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.arrow {
    width: 1.75vw;
    height: auto;
}

#portfoliowrap {
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-columns: 2 550px;
    -moz-columns: 2 550px;
    columns: 2 550px;
    -webkit-column-gap: 1.5em;
    -moz-column-gap: 1.5em;
    column-gap: 1.5em;
}

#wrap img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.portfolioimg {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 600px;
    margin-top: .75vw;
    margin-bottom: .75vw;
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    break-inside: avoid;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
    background-image: url(../images/trans.png);
}

.overlaytext {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 15px;
    color: white;
}

.footerbox {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    margin: 20px 0px 30px 0px;
}

.h_iframe {
    position:relative;
    clear:both;
}
.h_iframe .ratio {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
.h_iframe iframe {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%; 
    height:100%;
}

#contactform {
    padding-top: 3.4%;
}

.h_iframe {
    position:relative;
    clear:both;
}
.h_iframe .ratio {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
.h_iframe iframe {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%; 
    height:100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {

    #wrap {
        max-width: 1200px;
        padding: 0 0;
    }

    #header {
        height: 100 px;
    }

    #headerwrap {
        max-width: 1200px;
        padding: 0 0;
        height: 100px;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #293941;
    }

    .mobileimg {
        display: none;
    }

    .desktopimg {
        display: block;
    }

    .mobileheaderbar {
        display: block;
    }

    p {
        font-size: 19px;
    }

    h1 {
        font-size: 3.25em;
    }

    h2 {
        font-size: 2.5em;
    }

    h3 {
        font-size: 1.75em;
    }

    .footnote {
        font-size: 14px;
    }

    #nav {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    #logo {
        display: inline;
    }

    #logo img {
        height: 100px;
    }

    #squarelogo {
        display: none;
    }

    #landing {
        margin-top: 20px;
    }

    #lndmain {
        width: 74.9%;
        /*Not an even 75% to account for lndmain border-right*/
        border-right: 2px solid #293941;
    }

    #lndside {
        width: 20%;
        /*Not an even 25% to account for lndmain border-right*/
        clear: none;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin: 0 0 152px 4.9%;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
    }

    #lndmain h1{
        font-size: 8em;
        padding-top: 100px;
    }

    #lndmain h2{
        font-size: 3em;
        padding-bottom: 100px;
    }

    #lndside h1{
        font-size: 1.3em;
    }

    .projlogo {
        width: 25%;
        border-right: 2px solid #293941;
        padding: 2.5% 5% 2.5% 0px;
    }

    .projdesc {
        width: 64%;
        padding: 4.75% 0px 0px 5%;
        /*Not an even 65% to account for projlogo border-right*/
    }

    .dropbtn {
        display: none;
    }

    #nav a:nth-of-type(even){
        float: right;
        text-align: right;
    }
    /*This floats "Contact" to the right on desktop by floating only even numbered nav links to the right*/

    .twocolumn {
        -webkit-columns: 2 590px;
        -moz-columns: 2 590px;
        columns: 2 590px;

        -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
        -moz-column-gap: 20px;
        column-gap: 20px;

    }

    .thumb {
        height: 625px;
        position: relative;
    }

    .more {
        font-size: 2em;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0px;
    }

    .prevnext {
        font-size: 2em;
    }

    .arrow {
        width: 11px;
    }
}
```

htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

Sorry for the extended comments section, I try not to reach out on this site to avoid being a bother, and I see that I've had the opposite effect in flooding the comments.

It seems like things have sorted themselves out whether using www or not, but it'll probably still be a good idea to update my htaccess to force non-www.

Comment: I assume we cannot see the working page online?

Comment: This is not really a detailled question, you should include your css and your site hierarchy

Comment: I however had a look at your website, and https://www.mtbailey.com/fonts/Spartan%20MB/SpartanMB-Regular.woff seems to be a 404
Where did you put your fonts? Also avoid spaces in the Path and Url

Comment: Have you looked at the inspector console in the browser to check for errors?

Comment: Okay I found your problem, the fonts load correctly on the non www version of the website but your menu redirects to the www version which has a 404 on the fonts
See the difference
https://www.mtbailey.com/ https://mtbailey.com/

Now you need to troubleshoot why that is (likely htaccess related so I'd suggest you post your htaccess)

Comment: CSS can be found here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/17JOBrllHHTNLUiDLTDCwjkQwsbqj7OeU/view?usp=sharing. I wasn't sure how much detail would be needed since (as it seems to be a page-to-page problem) I didn't want to immediately just zip up my entire website and send it over. Perhaps that would have been the best course of action. Here is a screenshot of the general site structure: https://gyazo.com/2338d974234ae5f47e188e95ac5ee1d9

Comment: @Toffee see link for the htaccess file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YkjMEm26HIYaYjUXarigp4MQjTLFmEc4/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please include it as formatted code in your question, don't link to google drive files, thanks

Comment: Just remove the spaces in your css font url, and it will work, you should also add a redirect in your htaccess to force either the www website or the non www (recommend the latter)

Comment: @Toffee Not sure why I thought people opening random Drive links would be a good idea. See below:

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html

Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"`

Comment: Please review the stackoverflow guidelines and how to post a question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
You should edit your question taking into account the feedback in the comment rather than adding comments if you want an answer

Comment: @Toffee What spaces are you talking about specifically? I don't have any spaces in the URL directing to the font, do you mean the spaces before the format type?

Comment: It seems you did already, I meant the spaces in your css font declaration url